# Reading the same filename from multiple locations

Tags: python, string

I have an XML file named junit.xml in the same directory as my script, I can parse it by doing:

```
xml_file = os.path.abspath(__file__)
xml_file = os.path.dirname(xml_file)
xml_file = os.path.join(xml_file, "junit.xml")
root = ET.parse(xml_file).getroot();  # Where ET is the element tree
```

and everything is ok.

However, I have a more complex example where I need to parse a bunch files with the same name "junit.xml" that are in different directories in succession.

The directories are as follows:

```
\myhome\ireland\modules\builds\date1
\myhome\ireland\modules\builds\date2
\myhome\england\modules\builds\date1
\myhome\england\modules\builds\date2
\myhome\scotland\modules\builds\date1
\myhome\scotland\modules\builds\date2
\myhome\wales\modules\builds\date1
\myhome\wales\modules\builds\date2
\myhome\germany\modules\builds\date1
\myhome\germany\modules\builds\date2
```

Now, each directories has collection of XML files. I just want to get all the files named junit.xml under:

```
\myhome\ireland\modules\builds\date2
\myhome\england\modules\builds\date2
\myhome\scotland\modules\builds\date2
```

How can I do this in a pythonic way, where I can vary the names of the countries and the date when I need to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a string template for the path, for example:

```
path = r"\myhome\{}\modules\builds\date{}"
```

Which you can later use to construct the real path using the [**`str.format()`**](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) function (e.g. `path.format("ireland", 1)`).

Then, you can iterate over the country names and dates, and for each one parse the XML file:

```
for country in ["ireland", "england", "scotland"]:
    for num in [1, 2]:
        parse_xml(path.format(country, num))
```

Where `parse_xml` is a function you define which gets a path to an XML file and parses it.

Comment: I think directory should be `directory = "\\myhome\\{0}\\modules\\builds\\date{1}"`

Comment: @RanRag, since Python 2.7 (and also in Python 3.x), the positional arguments can be implicitly referenced, i.e. if `{}` is used then the next argument to `str.format` is taken. This is explained in the Python [documentation of format string](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#formatstrings).

Comment: ok, am using python 2.6 that's why I had to use my version of directory.

Comment: don't you think that using *rawstrings* (`r'...'`) look waaay better than using sooo many slashes (\\\)?

Answer (score 2):

First, define the "template" that your files will follow, then the list of countries and the list of dates:

```
dir_template = r'\myhome\%(country)s\modules\builds\%(date)s\junit.xml'
countries = ['ireland', 'england', 'scotland', 'wales', 'germany']
dates = ['date1', 'date2']

for c in countries:
    for d in dates:
        xml_file = dir_template % {'country': c, 'date': d}
        root = ET.parse(xml_file).getroot()
        # ...
```

Answer (score 2):

```
countries = ['england','wales','germany','etc']
countrypath = '\myhome\{}\modules\builds'
filename = 'junit.xml'
for country in countries:
    path = countrypath.format(country)
    for item in os.listdir(countrypath):
        if os.path.isdir(item) and item.startswith('date'):
            os.path.join(path, item, filename)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not so efficient as having a list of candidate directories beforehand, but you can also look for `junit.xml` files recursively using `os.walk` as follows:

```
import os

def get_junit_filenames(directory):
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(directory):
        if 'junit.xml' in filenames:
            yield os.path.join(dirpath, 'junit.xml')

for filename in get_junit_filenames('/myhome'):
    <process file>
```

This way you don't have to worry about adding/removing directories to your filesystem since the `junit.xml` files will be regardless of any change.

Answer (score 0):

```
    date = "dateX"
    countries = [ "ireland", "wales", "england"]

    for country in countries:
       path = "\myhome\%(country)s\modules\builds\%(date)s\junit.xml" \
% {"country" : country, "date": date}
       # check to see if the file you want is there?
       if os.path.exists(path):
           root = ET.parse(path).getroot();
```

Also the "os" module has a function called "walk" which allows you to walk an entire directory subtree. You might want to take a look at of you want ti "discover" all files called junit.xml and process them.